# Multiindex duplicated when rolling() applied on a groupby pandas object

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

I have got a bug with:

`x.field.rolling(window=5,min_periods=1).mean()`
where `x` is a `pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy` object.

I tried with the solution proposed in this [page](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15350). So I did this:

`x.field.apply(lambda x: x.rolling(window=5,min_periods=1).mean())`

Contrary to the webpage introduced above, I still get the same bug.

```
+---------+---------+-------+--------------------+
| machin  | machin  | truc  | a column of series |
+---------+---------+-------+--------------------+
| machin1 | machin1 | truc1 | 1                  |
|         |         | truc2 | 2                  |
|         |         | truc3 | 3                  |
|         |         | truc4 | 4                  |
| machin2 | machin2 | truc1 | 100                |
|         |         | truc2 | 99                 |
|         |         | truc3 | 98                 |
+---------+---------+-------+--------------------+
```

as you can see, the column index 'machin' is duplicated while before using the rolling method it appears correctly.

For instance let's write `x.field.apply(lambda x: x+1)`. It returns:

```
+---------+-------+--------------------+
| machin  | truc  | a column of series |
+---------+-------+--------------------+
| machin1 | truc1 | 2                  |
|         | truc2 | 3                  |
|         | truc3 | 4                  |
|         | truc4 | 5                  |
| machin2 | truc1 | 101                |
|         | truc2 | 100                |
|         | truc3 | 99                 |
+---------+-------+--------------------+
```

So no duplication, no bug. It shows that's really an issue from the `rolling()` method.

**Here some code to help you to reproduce my computation**

```
import pandas as pd

#creation of records
rec=[{'machin':'machin1',
    'truc':['truc1','truc2','truc3','truc4'],
    'a column':[1,2,3,4]},
    {'machin':'machin2',
    'truc':['truc1','truc2','truc3'],
    'a column':[100,99,98]}]

#creation of pandas dataframe
df=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(rec[0]),pd.DataFrame(rec[1])])

#creation of multi-index
df.set_index(['machin','truc'],inplace=True)

#creation of a groupby object
x=df.groupby(by='machin')

#rolling computation. Note that to do x.field or x['field'] is the same, and gives same bug as I checked.
x['a column'].rolling(window=5,min_periods=1).mean()

#rolling with apply and lambda, gives same bug
x['a column'].apply(lambda x:x.rolling(window=5,min_periods=1).mean())

#making apply and lambda alone gives no bug
a=x['a column'].apply(lambda x: x+1)
```

**Others solutions I tried**

I tried to reset the index of the series, [doc here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html).

```
a.reset_index(name='machin')
```

it raises an exception: `ValueError: cannot insert machin, already exists`

while you can see 'machin' in a names' value in the multiindex:

```
a.index
MultiIndex(levels=[['machin1', 'machin2'], ['machin1', 'machin2'],  ['truc1', 'truc2', 'truc3', 'truc4']],
       labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2]],
       names=['machin', 'machin', 'truc'])
```

I tried with drop too, [doc here](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop.html):

```
a.drop(index='machin')
a.drop(index=0)
```

it raises an exception: `KeyError: 'machin'` or `KeyError: 0`

**My versions**

Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 14 2018, 19:28:38) in an anaconda environment, even in terminal: [GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux

pandas 0.23.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `group_keys` argument of `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('machin', group_keys=False).rolling(window=5, min_periods=1).mean()
```

Alternatively, you can drop the 0th level, which rolling inserts, with `reset_index`:

```
df.groupby('machin').rolling(window=5, min_periods=1).mean().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

#### Output for either:

```
               a column
machin  truc           
machin1 truc1       1.0
        truc2       1.5
        truc3       2.0
        truc4       2.5
machin2 truc1     100.0
        truc2      99.5
        truc3      99.0
```

Comment: First option did not work for me. But second works very well. Thank you.

Comment: The first option didn't work for me either.

Comment: I think pandas has been active in this module recently. I just upgraded to version 1.3.5 and think this bug has been reintroduced.  I get it even with group_keys=False.